# Sparkle shows popup "App up to Date" every time on launch if app is in latest version

Tags: objective-c, macos, go, sparkle

I'm using Sparkle with Go App.

sparkle.m :

```
#import <Headers/SUUpdater.h>

static SUUpdater* updater = nil;

void sparkle_checkUpdates()
{
    if (!updater) {
        updater = [[SUUpdater sharedUpdater] retain];
    }

    [updater setUpdateCheckInterval:3600];
    [updater checkForUpdates:updater];
}
```

main.go :

```
func main() {
    sparkle.Sparkle_checkUpdates()
    // Some blocking call
}
```

I uploaded an appcast.xml file and Sparkle is working fine, the update is detected properly.

[image]

But after updating, on **every startup** of the app, an 'up to date' popup shows up :

[image]

I want this message to not show up. Popup should be shown only if an update is available.

For this I tried **replacing**

```
[updater checkForUpdates:updater];
```

with

```
[updater checkForUpdatesInBackground];
```

but now Sparkle doesn't work even if there's an update. No Popup shows up.

What am I missing here ?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why didn't you implement it the recommended way? IB Object connect with Suupdater? This will handle the update checks automatically without needing to create an updater Instance on each Start in main() and call the updater (this BTW is why it runs on each start!)

Comment: Keep in mind, that Sparkle won’t show dialogs when your Mac is in Do not disturb mode.